# Finding/approximating a "tangent line" for an empirical "curve"

Tags: geometry, optimization

From a data set with $N$ observations (indexed by $i$), I estimated an [empirical cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function), which is a discrete step curve $E$ that approximates a smooth curve $C$.

I want to estimate the intercept $a^*$ of a line $L^*$ with known slope $b^*$ such that $L^*$ is "tangent" to $C$. That is, I'm looking for:
$$\begin{align}
\hat a = \operatorname{arg} \min\ &a\\
\text{such that}\ &a + b^*x_i \geq y_i &\forall\ i\\
&(x_i,y_i) \in E &\forall\ i\\
\end{align}$$

The idea is that the optimal $\hat L$ here should be a decent estimate of the true $L^*$ that is tangent to $C$. What techniques can I use to compute $a$?

I feel like this should be pretty simple, since it's pretty easy to eyeball this curve on a graph. Here's an example in R:

```
set.seed(47730)
xx <- rgamma(15, 2, 2)
xx.ecdf <- ecdf(xx)
plot(xx.ecdf)
```

[image]

Let's say `b <- 1 / (max(xx) - min(xx))`, so $b \approx 0.37$. I can tell by inspection that I want to draw my estimated tangent line at the 2nd-to-last point (although in this case the estimator won't perform well). How can I algorithmically, numerically, or otherwise mathematically arrive at the same conclusion? I feel like it should be obvious but a solution isn't coming to me.

Here are the values in `xx`:

```
0.7768108
0.4624175
0.7212253
0.8780029
0.8162178
0.7246115
0.7819557
2.681145
2.834572
0.1784718
0.5814887
0.558649
0.5476705
0.3747524
0.1349413
```

Comment: How can I access the $y$ values from the $xx$ object in R?

Comment: @mvw `yy <- xx.ecdf(xx)`

Comment: I added a plot. Is that the tangent line you were looking for? (The one through the red point).

Comment: @mvw perfect, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a line
$$
f: y = a + b^* x
$$
with the constraint $y \ge y_i$ for all $N$ points $P_i = (x_i, y_i)$, so the line is above the all the $y_i$.

Idea: We change our coordinate system such that $f$ turns horizontal.
Then the $a_i$ of the largest $y'_i$ is feasible for all $y_i$.

A line with slope $b^*$ cuts the $x$-axis at an angle $\theta$ via:
$$
\tan(\theta) = b^* \Rightarrow \\
\theta = \arctan(b^*)
$$
A rotation about an angle $\theta$ is given by
$$
R(\theta) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We now transform all points via $R(-\theta)$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_i' \\
y_i'
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_i \\
y_i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
For an implementation, we would only calculate the $y'_i$ value:
\begin{align}
y'_i 
&= -\sin(\theta) \, x_i + \cos(\theta) \, y_i \\
&= -\frac{b^*}{\sqrt{1+(b^*)^2}} x_i + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(b^*)^2}} y_i \\
&= \frac{y_i - b^*\, x_i}{\sqrt{1+(b^*)^2}} \\
&= \frac{a_i}{\sqrt{1+(b^*)^2}} \quad (*)
\end{align}
where $a_i$ is the $a$ that would be picked if $f$ went through $(x_i, y_i)$:
\begin{align}
y_i &= a_i + b^* \, x_i \iff \\
a_i &= y_i - b^* \, x_i \quad (**)
\end{align}
We then select
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{argmax}{argmax}
k = \argmax_i y'_i
$$
This is the $k$ for the largest $y'_k$ where we put the line through.

As the denominator stays constant in equation $(*)$, the maximal $y'_i$ is the one with largest associated $a_i$ (via equation $(**)$).

So we found this interesting result:
$$
a = \max_i y_i - b^* \, x_i
$$

For the above data I get this image:

[image: example]
([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaABT.png))

Shown are the lines $y = y_i + b(x - x_i) = a_i + b x$, the red point is $A_4 = (x_4, y_4)$ which has the largest $a_i$.

Comment: This is a really clever solution. Not at all what I was expecting, but very straightforward.